# HTML header associated with table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with an uncertain amount of entries; on printable PDF pages I want that this table jumps to the next page when it doesn't fit on one page anymore, rather than cutting through the middle and this works well. However, i have a table name/description that says something about the table that I want to associate with the table and that jumps along with it, whenever the table jumps to the next page. Any idea on how to accomplish this?
Sorry if this seems trivial I'm not a CSS/HTML Guru any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have: I know there should be a body in the table but for some reason that doesn't go well with the tool I'm using

**CSS:**

```
.table_position
{
        table-layout:fixed;
        margin-top:15px;
        margin-bottom:15px;
        float:left;
        vertical-align:top; 
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        page-break-inside:avoid !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table_position">
        <span style="margin-left: 2%; color:rgb(245,132,31);">sample description</span>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left:2%; width:93%;" svmx-data="{{$sample_data}}" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="theader" svmx-data="{{$sample_date}}" width="35%">
                        <span>date</span></th>
                    <th class="theader" svmx-data="{{$sample_type}}" width="40%">
                        <span>type</span></th>
                    <th class="theader" svmx-data="{{$sample_quan}}" width="25%">
                        <span>quantity</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/0wdr69cz/

Comment: What are the “printable PDF pages” here and how do they relate to the problem? How does the code demonstrate the problem? How would any browser divide that output on two pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is rather simple: to use the HTML table tag `<caption>`

This does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the table description header in the very first row of your thead, and within a th with a colspan of 3?

I guess that'll work, then apply a class to style it separately. You can even remove the borders from that row and make it look like it's out of the table

Comment: When I do that, the table only consists of a single row because I have to give each header some data. If I don't assign anything, it generates an error. 
I do it like so:
<thead>
<tr> 
      <th colspan="3" svmx-data="{{$sample_data}}" width="100">
       <span>sample description</span></th>

Comment: What I was looking for is the HTML caption tag :) works like a charm!

Comment: glad to hear you solved it.
Answer your own question with the details on how you achieved it, for other users' future reference